# showing employers for friends in facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I have this code which is somewhat working.  the problem is that I cannot figure out how to show each seperate employer for my friends.

```
namespace WebApplication1.Site
{
  public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var accessToken = "access token";
      var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
      dynamic myInfo = client.Get("me/friends", new { fields = "name,id,work" });
      foreach (dynamic friend in myInfo.data)
      {
        Response.Write("Name: " + friend.name + " Employer: " + friend.work + "<br/><br/>");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to use this code:

```
Response.Write("Name: " + friend.name + "<br/>Employer: " + friend.work.employer + "<br/><br/>");
```

I get this result "*'Facebook.JsonArray' does not contain a definition for 'employer'*"

HELP!  (Using .net 4.5 if it matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your response, `friend.work` is an array, potentially with multiple employers (present and/or future) per friend. Also `friend.work.employer` is also an array, containing the id and name of each employer.

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cid%2Cwork

I'm not that familiar with c#, but I'm guessing you can't directly write an array, so you'll need to loop through `friend.work` with a `foreach` loop and concatenate each returned `employer.name` into a string.

You may run into trouble because not all friends have configured their work history, so you may have friends without `friend.work`. You'll need to deal with this possibility in your code.